# How to use jQuery datepicker as a control parameter for SqlDataSource?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, sqldatasource

I have the need to display a date in this format: dd/mm/yyyy. This is actually being stored in an ASP.NET textbox and being used as a control parameter for a select on the GridView. When the query is run, though, the date format should change to 'd M y' (for Oracle). It is not working. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Right now I am pushing the "new" format to a invisible label and using the label as my control param:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            //datepicker for query, shown traditionally but holding an Oracle-needed format
            $('[id$=txtBeginDate]').datepicker({ minDate: -7 , altFormat: 'd M y' });
            //get alt format
            var altFormat = $('[id$=txtBeginDate]').datepicker("option", "altFormat");
            //set date to be altformat
            $('[id$=lblActualDate]').datepicker("option", "altFormat", 'd M y');
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not do the formatting on the server-side when building your Oracle query?

```
System.DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(txtBeginDate.Text);
dt.ToString("dd MM yyyy")
```

Answer (score 1):

SqlDataSource can only use server-side asp.net controls for ControlParameters. To use your jQuery datepicker, you'll have to get a little fancy.

Put a plain Parameter and then handle the SqlDataSource's Selecting event to set the value for the parameter from the Request object (with suitable validation and formatting) by hand.